# How to enable GitHub clone using SSL Certificate?

Tags: github, digital-signature

I am new to GitHub.

1. Is it possible to clone GitHub private repos using SSL certificate?
2. Is CLI operations to GitHub & GitHub APIs can be done using SSL certificates?

Comment: "Is it possible to clone GitHub private repos using SSL certificate?" - The GitHub website explains precisely how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, sure, I am on it. I also do not Want to use personal access token for clone.